# Creating a vs.net 2013 solution with multiple projects, nuget is causing real problems

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget, visual-studio-2013

When other developers get the vs.net 2013 solution from TFS, Nuget doesn't seem to work as expected and many of the individual projects in the solution do not have the required dll's downloaded (although they are defined in the packages.config file).

If I go to view the installed packages, it shows up as they are installed and the correct projects are selected.

I went into console and ran:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

After doing this, my packages.config file was truncated for whatever reason and 80% of my packages were removed from the config file!

What should I be looking into as it is either I have setup the solution incorrectly or nuget just isn't reliable.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that **NuGet Packages Restore** is turned **ON**. 
This forces to restore missing binaries directly from NuGet server. You can right click on Solution and enable this option as follow:
[image]

Make sure that .nuget folder that contains nuget.exe is created under your Solution.

Comment: You really don't want to do that. Here's why http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make sure that you have automatic package restore turned on in VS 2013. You can do this in the options.

[image: Make sure automatic package restore is on.]

Then, when you build, VS should grab the packages for you. If you want to manually restore the packages or do it from powershell, you'll want to use the command `nuget.exe restore` in the folder your solution lives in.

If you're using custom package sources, you'll want to make sure you specified them in your nuget.config file.